# Migrated JFrog from On-premise to AWS Cloud but my artifacts are showing only 40 where as we used to have 200k+ artifacts

Tags: jfrog-cli

I am trying to migrate our on-premise JFrog artifactory to AWS cloud. I have followed the "Method-1" [instructions](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/).

Even I have mounted a file system and moved the filestore content to that location and set it as Home directory.

[image]

But, still I am only able to see 40 artifacts showing. Not sure what is causing the issue.